# Ranks of Composition of Linear Transformations vs. Mapped Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm having trouble with this proof:

> Let $\mathbb{U, V, W}$ be finite dimensional vector spaces and let $L: \mathbb{V} \to \mathbb{U}$ and $M : \mathbb{U} \to \mathbb {W}$ be linear mappings
>
> a) Prove that rank$(M \circ L) \leq $ rank$(M)$.
>
> b) Prove that rank$(M \circ L) \leq $ rank$(L)$.

I've attempted a), I've gone as far as showing

rank$(M) \leq $ dim$(\mathbb{U})$ and rank$(M \circ L)$ $\leq $ dim$(\mathbb{V})$

with the Rank-Nullity theorem, and but that obviously doesn't get me very far. I'm not sure how else to approach this. Haven't attempted b), as I'd imagine it extends off of a).

Comment: How do you know $\dim U\le \dim V$?

Comment: Hint for (a) $L(\mathbb V) \subseteq \mathbb U \implies M(L(\mathbb V)) \subseteq M(\mathbb U)$.

Comment: @Bernard I just realized that was incorrect

Comment: Rank $(M\circ L)$ is at most the greater of the rank ($M$) or the rank ($L$). $(M\circ L)$ can only take vectors in the image of $L$ and take them to some place $\mathbb W.$ Similarly no matter how rich the image of $L$ is, if the rank of $M$ is smaller than the rank of $L$ then some of those vectors are in the kernel of $M.$

Comment: @DougM conceptually I understand why the inequality holds, I have no idea how to prove it though

Comment: @user251257 if that implies the dim$M(L\mathbb{V}) \leq m(\mathbb{U})$ does that complete the proof for part a?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

Consider the linear maps $f$ and $g$ associated to the matrices $L$ and $M$ respectively. $\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{Im}\DeclareMathOperator{\rk}{rank}$ We know $ML$ is associated to the composition $g\circ f$.

We know $\;\rk L=\dim\im f$,  $\;\rk M=\dim\im g$,  $\;\rk ML=\dim\im (g\circ f)$.

- How do the subspaces $\im (g\circ f)$ and $\im g$ compare?
- How do $\dim\im f$ and $\dim V$ compare? And $\dim\im(g\circ f)$ and $\dim V$?

Comment: I've come back to this question now... and I'm stuck again (this time on b). Your hint says to find the comparison between dim Im $f$ and dim $\mathbb{V}$, and dim Im $g \circ f$ and dim $\mathbb{V}$. The only thing I can really find is that they are both less than or equal to dim $\mathbb{V}$, which again doesn't give me anything. Is there something I'm not getting?

Comment: You have to use that the image of $g\circ f$ is the image of the *restriction of* $g$  to $\operatorname{Im}f$, so the dimension of this image is at most the dimension of the source, which is $\operatorname{rank}L$.

Comment: We haven't learned what restrictions are and it doesn't look like it's in the book. Is there an alternative way to arrive at that conclusion?

Comment: Is it fair to say that for some $\vec{v} \in \mathbb{V}$, $L\vec{v} = 0$ implies $M(L(\vec{v})) = 0$, so ker($L$) $\subseteq$ ker($ML$) and by Rank-Nullity Theorem, rank($ML$) $\leq$ rank($L$)?

Comment: A  restriction is a very general notion for *maps* between sets. It has nothing to do with linear algebra. It only means you restrict the domain to a subset (subspace in the present case). rank($ML$) $\le$ rank($L$) for a *much simpler* reason than the rank-nullity theorem: the image of $g\circ f$ is  the image by $g$ of  Im($f$).

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. The question was listed under the rank-nullity theorem section, so I assume that's the approach that was implied for me to take. I'll keep that property in mind for next time.